# Elegent way to set variables in .ini files

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I'm currently trying to script the installation of Microsoft Sql Server 2012, and I've run into a problem with letting the user set options for the installation process in my powershell script

Because sql server's options are set in an .ini file, I'm not sure what the best way to edit said .ini file is. I could see myself

- Copying the whole .ini file in powershell and setting variables within the quotes to write it out later, or
- saving the ini file separately and searching for each line I need to set variables as a string to edit separately.

Is there any more elegant way to work with .ini files than this?
Is there any "find and replace" powershell module for files that I could use?

Comment: Probably best to re-write the entire .ini file from an "in-script" variable that contains your template because then you can guarantee that the content will be what you need it to be (plus the values the user sets)...

Comment: "Is there any "find and replace" PowerShell module for files that I could use?"  INI files are just text, any of PS's standard find and replace commands would work on one.  Load the file into memory, find and replace, dump back to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the .ini as a text file. Say we have the following .ini:

```
[section1]
var1=foo1
[section2]
var2=foo2
var3=foo3
```

To change the value assigned to "var2", we can do:

```
(get-content .\test.ini).Replace('foo2','bar2') | Set-Content .\test.ini
```

Where "bar2" is the user defined value. To incorporate the user defined value, you could do:

```
$ini = ".\test.ini"
$userInput = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a new value for var2"
(get-content $ini).Replace('foo2',$userInput) | Set-Content $ini
```

The way you choose to design how you handle the replace will rely on the data in your particular file.

Comment: This is a bit too simple, what if there are multiple entries with `=foo2`, you need to specify the value-name as well. What if there are duplicate value-names in different sections?

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/brandoncomputer/vds

```
function inifile ($a,$b,$c,$d){
switch ($a){ 
    open {
        $global:inifile = $b
    } 
    write {
        $Items = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
        $content = get-content $global:inifile
        if ($content)
        {
            $Items.AddRange($content)
        }
        if ($Items.indexof("[$b]") -eq -1)
            {
            $Items.add("")
            $Items.add("[$b]")
            $Items.add("$c=$d")
            $Items | Out-File $global:inifile
            }
        else
        {
        For ($i=$Items.indexof("[$b]")+1; $i -lt $Items.count; $i++) 
        {
        if ($Items[$i].length -gt $c.length)
            {
            if ($Items[$i].substring(0,$c.length) -eq $c -and ($tgate -ne $true))
                {
                    $Items[$i] = "$c=$d"
                    $tgate = $true
                }
            }
            if ($Items[$i].length -gt 0)
            {
                if (($Items[$i].substring(0,1) -eq "[") -and ($tgate -ne $true))
                {
                    $i--
                    $Items.insert(($i),"$c=$d")
                    $tgate = $true
                    $i++
                }
            }               
        }
        if ($Items.indexof("$c=$d") -eq -1)
        {
            $Items.add("$c=$d")
        }

        $Items | Out-File $global:inifile -enc ascii
        }
    } 
}}
```

Usage

1. inifile open c:\temp\myini.ini
2. inifile write header footer value

$a = $(iniread header footer)

```
function iniread($a,$b) {
$Items = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$content = get-content $global:inifile
if ($content)
{
    $Items.AddRange($content)
}
if ($Items.indexof("[$a]") -eq -1)
    {
    $return = ""
    }
else
{
    $return = ""
    For ($i=$Items.indexof("[$a]")+1; $i -lt $Items.count; $i++) 
    {
    if ($Items[$i].length -gt $b.length)
        {
        if ($Items[$i].substring(0,$b.length) -eq $b -and $gate -ne $true)
            {
                $return = $Items[$i].split("=")[1]
                $gate = $true
            }
        }
        if ($Items[$i].length -gt 0)
        {
            if (($Items[$i].substring(0,1) -eq "[") -and ($tgate -ne $true))
            {$gate = $true}
        }
    }
}return $return}
```